# Passing data from joomla view to joomla template file in joomla 1.7

Tags: joomla1.7, joomla-template, joomla-component

I want to know how can I pass data from joomla view to joomla template. How can I pass multiple variables?

```
     class CareerformViewCareerform extends JView
     {
   protected $state;
    protected $item;

  function display($tpl = null)
  {
        $app        = JFactory::getApplication();
    $params     = $app->getParams();

    // Get some data from the models
    $state      = $this->get('State');
    $item       = $this->get('Item');
            $newvar="Something";
            $success_message="Thanks for your interest";

       parent::display($tpl);

  }
    }
```

I want to pass `$newvar` and `$success_message` to template; how can I pass them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can pass view data to template  by using:

```
$var1="Some string";
$this->assignRef('var1',$var1);
```

Please note that `assignRef` pass second param by reference and we can retrieve it as

```
echo $this->var1;
```

not just `$var1` but `$this->var1`

Comment: Where is the function assignRef() defined in this case view or template?